# What are the Matrikas exactly?

Tags: mantras, sadhana, upasana, matrika, mantra-diksha

Say for example, if I say the word “Narayana”, as such, there is no problem.

But if I chant “Om Namo Narayana” which is a mantra, in the absence of Diksha, it may be a problem(death and permanent insanity are two outcomes that I’ve heard)

In both cases, the word “Narayana” comes, but in the mantra, all the syllables are “matrikas”.

So does it mean that even chanting “Narayana “ in itself is wrong? (Logically I feel like it isn’t, but I’d like an answer clarifying this)

Comment: Within the Tantrik system, Matrikas are the mystical power present behind every letter. It is the matrikas which constitute the power behind every mantra, thus making the mantras different from ordinary words (like how the words spoken by a judge while passing verdicts at courts bears power over the words spoken by him/her outside the court). As the presiding deity of speech, Sarasvati rules over the Matrikas.

Comment: Adding to Anubrataji matrikas rule over Swara and Vyanjan. Here, 'Narayana' is ruled by matrikas too. Swara अ to अ: (a to ah) is ruled by Lakshmi. 'त'(T) varg is ruled by Vaishnavi matrika , 'य'(y) is ruled by Andri matrika 'ट'(tt) is ruled by Kaumari matrika. **Thus here the word 'Narayana' is ruled by Vaishnavi (न), Āindri(र, य), Kumari (ण) and all 'आ' by Lakshmi.**

Comment: @Chamundadas Would you please link an answer/reference explaining the Matrikas in detail?Thanks!

Comment: *Nārāyaṇa* is just a nāma of Bhagavān, anyone can do its japa, regardless of who they are. Also, regardless of who you are, you can even do japa of 'nārāyaṇāya namaḥ', the praṇava shouldn't be included unless one has Vedādhikāra.